# How to get multiple cursors out of single OUT cursor

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-cursor

I have such function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_request
(IN p_id TEXT, 
OUT c_request REFCURSOR)
AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN

DECLARE 

    cur_1 CURSOR FOR select id, title, doc_url, icon_url
                      from request_attachments
                      where request_attachments.id = requests.id;
        
    cur_2 CURSOR FOR  select users.id user_id, 
                              users.name user_name, 
                              users.email user_email,
                              users.picture_url user_picture, 
                              request_comments.ts, 
                              request_comments."comment"
                        from request_comments, users
                        where request_comments.id = p_id and request_comments.user_id = users.id
                        order by request_comments.id desc, request_comments.ts desc;
        

BEGIN
open c_request for
    select requests.center_id, 
    cur_1 attachments,
    cur_2 comments
    from requests
    where id = p_id;
    
END;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And I would like to get values from cursors that are defined inside c_request cursor in this function.
I have written something like this:

```
c_kur = get_request('some id here');
loop
  fetch c_kur into r_kur;
  IF NOT FOUND THEN EXIT; END IF;



    c_kur2 = r_kur.cur_1;
    loop
      fetch c_kur2 into r_kur2;
      IF NOT FOUND THEN EXIT; END IF;
      raise info 'user_id: %, comment: %', r_kur2.user_id, r_kur2."comment";  --THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO SEE THOSE VALUES
    end loop;




end loop;
close c_kur;
```

But it doesn't seem to work. How to get cur_1 and cur_2 values from this function
in nested loop like above?

I am getting this error:

```
NOTICE:  cursor "cur_1" does not exist 34000
```

Answer (score 0):

No one was able to help me, but I have solved this issue by rewriting this function completely. Now I have two additional "helper" functions that are returning cursors separately and this main get_request function is returning only c_request cursor without cur_1 and cur_2 cursors (they are handled by helper functions).

It works slower, but it works. ;)